# Selenium getting stale data

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to read data from a webpage in which a value inside a table cell is updated in background by java script. It gets the data first time correctly. But after the javascript has updated it, it still gives the old value.

How can I make sure that it gets the updated data without forcing a refresh of the web page? The web page doesn't need any human interaction and updates the content automatically every few seconds.

```
            driver = new FirefoxDriver(@"drivers");

            //First login to the website
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://abc.MaskedForStackOverFlow/auth-login.php");
            var userNameTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Id("username"));
            var passwordTextBox = driver.FindElement(By.Name("password"));
            var termsCheckBox  = driver.FindElement(By.Id("loginTermsAndConditions"));
            var loginButton = driver.FindElement(By.Name("btnlogin"));

            
            userNameTextBox.SendKeys("abcd@gmail.com");
            passwordTextBox.SendKeys("password");
            termsCheckBox.Click();
            loginButton.Click();

            //Go to actual page
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://abc.MaskedForStackOverFlow/product-details.php");

            //Continously get the order count and print it.
            do
            {
                var orderCountLabel = driver.FindElement(By.Id("order_count"));
                
                Console.WriteLine($"{DateTime.Now} : Order Count: {orderCountLabel.Text}");

                Thread.Sleep(5000);
            } while (true);
```

I already read this [Guide](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/selenium-tutorials/how-to-work-with-ajax-controls-using-webdriver) but my situation is different as the element is always displayed, it just gets updated periodically.

Comment: you should probably use the new expected condition for stalenessOf.  Once it goes stale, you can get the value again:  https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf(org.openqa.selenium.WebElement)  While this is false, you sleep... while it's true you re-get the element and it's value.

Comment: Is that `do` loop your actual code? I don't think it is... that code should actually work because you are fetching the element each time it loops right before printing.